# Slow speeds (40mb/s) from Crucial X6 on USB 3 port?

Tags: usb, ssd, performance

I'm running an Asus b350m TUF board, and I just got hold of a Crucial X6 USB SSD, and when I ran crystaldiskmark on it, the read and write speeds were around 40-44mb/s, nothing higher. Random 4k access speeds were reported as around 10megabytes/s.

I've tried 2 methods - one uses the original crucial USB-C to USB-C cable and then goes into a USB-C to USB-A adapter, and the other uses a third-party USB-C to USB-A cable. Both of the USB-A ends went into a blue USB 3 port, and both yield the same low speeds.

I tried using usbtreeview and found this.

[image: USBtreeview report]

Seems like it is usb superspeed capable, but its connecting at usb high speed only.

Another device, a USB HDD DAS, can connect at superspeed on the same port, so that makes me believe the problem is the device? I'm using both the original cable and third party cable, and both give the same slow speeds.

Does anyone know what is wrong? I thought USB 3 supported higher speeds than this. I'm already using all the latest BIOS and drivers for this board.

Comment: There seems to be six USB3 ports on your mobo. Do you have all ports not connecting at SS rates?

Comment: Could it be that you are trying the device on a port on front-panel of PC case?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using usbtreeview and found this.

I am not familiar with this utility but the screenshot is telling me that the port does not support USB 3.x.

> Another device, a USB HDD DAS, can connect at superspeed on the same port, so that makes me believe the problem is the device? I'm using both the original cable and third party cable, and both give the same slow speeds.

Are you also using the same cable, or does this device have a captive cable?  It's possible the cable is the problem.  Are you sure you are using the same port?  Something isn't adding up.

> Both of the USB-A ends went into a blue USB 3 port, and both yield the same low speeds.

Don't trust the color, it can lie to you. A USB 3.x port must have five little contacts at the edge of the connector and four larger contacts behind them.  If you don't see those five contacts then it's not a USB 3.x port.

> I'm using both the original cable and third party cable, and both give the same slow speeds.

The cable that came with the drive should support the full speed of the drive.  Are you sure that you are plugging it into a USB 3.x port?  And the cable is a USB 3.x cable?

> I've tried 2 methods - one uses the original crucial USB-C to USB-C cable and then goes into a **USB-C to USB-A adapter**, and the other uses a third-party USB-C to USB-A cable.

Wait... Wut?  A USB-C to USB-A adapter?  Take this adapter, find a hammer, smash the adapter to pieces with the hammer, burn the shattered remains of the adapter over a blue flame, then bury the ashes where nobody will find them.  This adapter is a fire waiting to happen.  I can cite many sources on why you need to destroy this adapter, this is just one:

https://medium.com/@leung.benson/why-are-there-no-usb-c-receptacle-to-usb-b-plug-or-usb-a-plug-adapters-f97736bb62be

The short of it all is that an adapter with a USB-C receptacle can allow for the connection of two USB ports that supply power, and this can mean shorting out the power supplies on the two devices and putting a lot of current through some tiny wires.  This can start the cable on fire.  The USB people do not allow this adapter in their spec for this reason.  I don't know why but these adapters are showing up seemingly everywhere now when they should not exist.

That adapter might be only USB 2.0, that might explain the drive speed problem with the included adapter.  However that adapter is wired it needs to go away, it's nothing but trouble.

I'd double check that the port and cable are USB 3.x.  I'd only do that after the USB-C to USB-A adapter is destroyed.  Seriously, that adapter is all kinds of wrong and needs to be gone.

Comment: In USB, one physical port (blue-colored usually), gets mapped to TWO different  root instances. In this particular case/port, if the device connects as HS, it appears under HS section (port6). If the device gets connected at SS speed, it will appear as port2 in the USBTreeView. Again, physically the connector is the same. FYI.

Comment: Regarding the sentiments about USB-C receptacle-to-USB-A-plugs, you are making an assumption that OP has a passive adapter. Your assumption can be wrong. In fact, there are many adapters of this kind that use simple CC-controller and a high-side power switch to be in compliance with USB-C specifications. And even side-swap muxes are used as well.

Comment: @Ale..chenski  The USB spec explicitly forbids an adapter that has a USB-C female receptacle and USB-A male jack.  You can argue that active adapters exist and that they are safe to use, but you cannot argue that they are in compliance with the USB spec.  Since the behavior of these adapters is not defined in the USB spec it is impossible to claim they comply.

Comment: Then call the device "port converter" instead of "legacy adapter". I think the verbage of Type-C specification narrowly refers to "legacy passive assemblies". The section 2.2 is named "USB Type-C Receptacles, Plugs and Cables". There is no technical reason why the active "converter" cannot satify all USB/Type-C/PD port requirements.

Comment: " There is no technical reason why the active "converter" cannot satify all USB/Type-C/PD port requirements. "  There is a reason, the USB spec does not define how this kind of active converter is supposed to function.  I suspect known brands get away with selling these by not claiming that they meet any USB spec, there's no USB trident icon on any of them.  The fly-by-night companies get away with it by not caring, if the USB enforcers come looking then they just close up shop and sell them under a different brand the next day.

Answer (score -1):

Format the X6 as NTFS. Speeds are remarkably higher than with the exFat format it comes with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).